# Addresses displayed in radare2

Tags: radare2

I am disassembling a binary with radare2 and I see some lines like this:

```
|  0x004007f1   488b05981820.  mov rax, qword [0x00602090] ; 0x602090:8]=0x400c60
```

I do not understand, what are the addresses `0x00602090` or `0x400c60` ?

What are the differences between the two ?

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that the first address, `0x00602090` is the location from where the value will be loaded into the `rax` register. The second one, `0x400c60` is what is located in that memory location. r2 is giving you hints about the actual result might be in the comments. It also informs you that 8 byte will be used for the operation with the `:8` suffix.

So it looks like that at address `0x602090` there's a 8-byte value stored that constitutes as an address `0x400c60`.